# adding a column which is an equation to a html table using JQuery PHP with SQL

Tags: php, jquery, json

well the title may sound confusing but what im trying to do is create a php which will return a JSON array of countries. This JSON array is then converted into a HTML table. I have done the html side but i am struggling with the php side. Im not necessary asking for code, just some guidance or an example. I am struggling with linking the html with php. I have a x y and z user input where they enter a number and i have created an equation for this. I have added the extra column in the html side, however i am having difficulties with the php. Below is my html code and my php attempt. Any idea how i can go about it?

```
<html>  
<head>  
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            var x ='x';
            var y = 'y';
            var z = 'z';
            
            
            $('<tr><td>'+x+'</td>' +
                  '<td><input id="'+x+'" class="textbox" type="text" value="1" />'+
                  '</td></tr>').appendTo('#menu');
                  
             $('<tr><td>'+y+'</td>'+
                  '<td><input id="'+y+'" class="textbox" type="text" value="1" />'+
                  '</td></tr>').appendTo('#menu');
                  
             $('<tr><td>'+z+'</td>'+
                  '<td><input id="'+z+'" class="textbox" type="text" value="1" />'+
                  '</td></tr>').appendTo('#menu');
                 
                    // creating Variable x y z for user input
                
            $('<tr><td><b>Please enter the number of results</b></td>'+
                  '<td><input id="num" type="text" class="textbox" value="10" />'+ // allows user to change the number of countries
                  '</td></tr>').appendTo('#menu');  
            
            $('<tr><td></td><td><input id="button" type="button" onClick="obtainCountries()" value="Submit"/>'+
              '</td></tr>').appendTo('#menu'); // Inserting a Submit button to allow user to obtain results
            
            $('<table id="resulttable"/>').appendTo('#result');
        });

        
        function formula(x,y,z,b,s,g) { 
            return (((2*x) * bronze) + ((4*y) * silver) + (8*z * gold));
        }
        
        function orderCountries() { 
            //will load view.php, which will return a JSON array of countries
            //this is then used to create a table of results

            $.get("view.php",{x:$('#x').val(),y:$('#y').val(),z:$('#z').val()},
                function(data) {
                    for(elem in data[0])
                        $("<th>"+elem+"</th>").appendTo('#resulttable');
                    $("<th>formula val</th>").appendTo('#resulttable');
                    for(var i = 0; i < $('#num').val(); i++) {
                        $('<tr id="row'+i+'"/>').appendTo('#resulttable');
                        for(elem in data[i]) {
                            $("<td>"+data[i][elem]+"</td>").appendTo('#row'+i);
                        }
                        $("<td>"+formula($('#x').val(),$('#y').val(),$('#z').val(),
                        data[i]['bronze'],data[i]['silver'],data[i]['gold'])+"</td>").appendTo('#row'+i);
                    }
                },'json')
        }
        
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Creating Equation using Olympics database</h1>
    <h3 style="text-align:center">My Formula = ((2x*bronze)+(4y*silver)+(8z*gold))</h3>

    <table id="menu">
    <tr>
        <th scope="colhead">The Variables</th>
        <th scope="colhead">Input</th>
    </tr>

    </table>
    <div id="result"/>
</body>

</html>
```

Below is my PHP

```
<?php
require_once 'MDB2.php';

include "/diska/www/include/coa123-mysql-connect.php"; //to provide $username,$password



$db =& MDB2::connect($dsn); 
if(PEAR::isError($db))
    { 
        die($db->getMessage());
    }
    
    
$x = $_GET["x"];
$y = $_GET["y"];
$z = $_GET["z"];





$db->setFetchMode(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
$sql="SELECT ISO_id, gdp, population, country_name, gold, silver, bronze, total
FROM Country WHERE '$x'='0' AND '$y'='0' AND '$z'='0'"


$res =& $db->query($sql);
if(PEAR::isError($res))
{
    die($res->getMessage());
}



echo json_encode($res->fetchAll());

?>
```

Comment: "i am having difficulties" Will you be more specific? What do you expect to happen and what is really happening?

Comment: Oh yes and x y z variables are not in the MySQL database

Comment: I expect when i click on the submit button that the tables will appear with the values

Comment: What is happening is i am getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 30  on the php side

Comment: First, you are attempting to access elements that don't exist in the document: `$('#x').val()`. Where is the element with ID 'x' in your HTML?

Comment: Which is line 30 in the PHP script?

Comment: $res =& $db->query($sql);

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). DO **NOT** USE THIS CODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the parse error because you are leaving out a semicolon after constructing the sql query

```
$sql="SELECT ISO_id, gdp, population, country_name, gold, silver, bronze, total FROM Country WHERE '$x'='0' AND '$y'='0' AND '$z'='0'"
```

Comment: Ha, I missed it too. Nice catch!